# Querying for all solar farms in the UK using OSM and QGIS

Tags: qgis, query, united-kingdom, solar-radiation, quickosm

I'm using the query function in QuickOSM plugin

```
[out:json];
area["name"=United Kingdom"]->.searchArea;
nwr(area.searchArea)["generator:source"="solar['generator:output:electricity'='yes'];
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

But it is not returning any results. It runs and then disappears. If I use Overpass Turbo it times out.

How can I do this?

Comment: Increasing timeout time does not work?

Comment: any recommendation for the amount of timeout?

Comment: Just trial and error... try increasing... 60s, 300s, 900s...? `[out:json][timeout:60];`

Comment: fyi if you download the csv and filter by Solar Photovoltaics you will get the solar farms with Eastings and Northings (OSGB36) https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/1008403/renewable-energy-planning-database-q2-june-2021.csv/preview

Comment: Thanks but I need the outline boundaries!

Answer (score 2):

For polygons of **Solar Panels Farm areas** in the England, Wales and Scotland.

[image]

Source of data and available for download (166.5 MB) is
https://zenodo.org/record/4059881

Using OSM based data in GeoJSON format.
(If want to edit the data suggest convert to shapefile or geopackage first)